# Multidimensional 3D Cell Arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

how can i create this multidimensional 3D Cell array?
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ch_data_struct6.gif
[image]

Comment: Since cell array can hold any other Matlab type (including cell arrays), you can just fill put data into it.

Comment: Well, i actually need to create a 3D Cell Array where each cell has 5 variables (of different types) that i can assign values to later on using a for loop for instance.
I'm having a problem with the syntax of such structure.

Comment: @Rotem ........

Comment: OK, attached image illustrates output format, but what is the format of the input? Please post your code (what have you got so far?).

Answer (score 0):

The image you've linked does not depict a 3D Cell array, but instead a 3D Structure array. For example, the structure containing the information of the first 'patient' could be constructed by:

```
patient(1,1,2).name = 'Al Smith';
patient(1,1,2).billing = 504.70;
patient(1,1,2).test = [80 80 80; 153 153 154; 181 190 183];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the first patient:

```
%Allocate 3D empty cell array (cell array dimension is 2x2x2).
patient = cell(2, 2, 2);

%Set details of first patient.
patient{1, 1, 2}.name = 'Al Smith'; %Set name field (string).
patient{1, 1, 2}.billing = 504.70;  %Set billing field (double).
patient{1, 1, 2}.test = [80, 80, 80; 153, 153, 154; 181, 190, 182]; %Set test field (3x3 matrix).

%Continue with next patient:
patient{1, 2, 2}.name = 'Dora Jones';
%...
%...
```